# Grab the second number and the word after it using regexp

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string:

```
str = "1 - hello world 1234 abc 5678 def"
```

I want to grab `1234 abc` from the string.

My current implementation `str[/\d+\s*\D*$/]` only grabs the last number with the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```rb
str[/\d+\D+(\d+\s*\w+)/, 1]
str[/\d+\D+\K\d+\s*\w+/]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k1vJrA/1) and [this regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/k1vJrA/2).

Here, only the first regex match is searched for. *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\D+` - one or more non-digits
- `(\d+\s*\w+)` - Group 1: one or more digits, zero or more whitespaces, and one or more word chars
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far.

**NOTE**:

- If a "word" is a chunk of non-whitespace chars, replace `\w+` with `\S+`
- If you want to support float values (numbers with fractional parts), you will need to replace `\d+` with `\d*\.?\d+` or `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` patterns.

Here is a [Ruby test](https://ideone.com/MhYrNz):

```rb
str = "1 - hello world 1234 abc 5678 def"
puts str[/\d+\D+(\d+\s*\w+)/, 1]
# => 1234 abc
puts str[/\d+\D+\K\d+\s*\w+/]
# => 1234 abc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But in my case, the number can have more than one digit. So in that case, I had to slightly modify the `(\d+\s*\w+)` part and made it `\d*` (edited the question).

Comment: @S.Goswami `+` means ***one or more***. So, you are safe with `\d+`.